# React Route overriding redux thunk reducer fetch call

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I have a weird issue, I have a navlink that routes to /posts/:postId and in my app component a route that registers that to view a single post. When I dispatch , my thunk route is different to hit my backend, (im using the same route in separate components). Yet in this component when I dispatch it adds on a /posts at the beginning of the route I need to hit so it always errors out saying not found, because it does not exists.   but when I change the navlink to exclude /posts and make it just /${postId} everything works just fine.  Not sure why the Route is adding on a /posts prefix to my csrf fetch call.  You guys ever run into something like this before?

```
<Route path='/posts/:postId' exact={true} >
            <SinglePost />
          </Route>
```

```
<NavLink className='delete-post-content' to={`posts/${postId}`}>Go to post</NavLink>
```

```
const response = await csrfFetch(`api/users/posts/${comment.postId}/comments/delete`,
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

when you link to posts/ its a relative address
but
when you link to /posts/ its a absolute path
so make sure to use a slash(/) before link

Comment: Ah, i see that, I added the slash, but resulted in the same issue, it still prepends /posts/api/users in the fetch call when it should just be /api/users

Comment: it may because of a baseurl you have set. i should see your router path all

Comment: your right, I totally forgot about my csrfFetch function, now I need to figoure out how to re-write this 

```
export async function csrfFetch(url, options = {}) {
options.method = options.method || "GET";
options.headers = options.headers || {};

 if (options.method.toUpperCase() !== "GET") {
    options.headers["Content-Type"] =
      options.headers["Content-Type"] || "application/json";
    options.headers["XSRF-Token"] = Cookies.get("XSRF-TOKEN");
  }

 const res = await window.fetch(url, options);
```

Comment: no, i mean your routing path dude, where are you setting your routing to component, i need them

Comment: I found it, in the csrfFetch call, I put a '/' infront of api/users and that solved it, thank you

Comment: You've it exactly backwards. Paths ***without*** a leading slash `"/"` character are relative (*to the parent route*) paths, while paths ***with*** a leading slash are absolute paths. https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#link